# ¿Porque al utilizar un UNION y mostrar datos no se muestran correctamente?

Tags: java, mysql, jtable

Tengo un JTable en el cual se desplega informacion de dos tablas, el UNION funciona correctamente, y la informacion se muestra de manera correcta, el detalle llega cuando agrego a visualizar la column abono, son datos double y a la hora de mostrarlo en mi JTable los muestra de la siguiente manera:

[image: Informacion Abono]

```
Les dejo mi consulta: 

try {
            
            prueba();
            Statement sql = Conexion.getConexion().createStatement();
            String consulta = "  SELECT codigo,nombre,pago_parcial,total "
                    + "FROM ptjs_accounted\n"
                    + "WHERE po = '" + valor1 + "'"
                    + "UNION SELECT  SUBSTRING(accountcode, 1,15), accountcode, coo, abono "
                    + "FROM pr_gastos_detalle \n"
                    + "WHERE idc = '" + valor1 + "'"
                    + "AND accountcode LIKE '2%'";
            
            ResultSet rs = sql.executeQuery(consulta);
            tablaPorFechas.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
```

Los datos y tipo de dato de las tablas involucradas en mi bdd mysql:

[image: img]

Los tipos de dato que coinciden en la misma columna de las tablas son diferentes. en el caso de ptjs_accounted el tipo de dato en la columna total (abono)es de tipo varchar y en pr_gastos_detalle es de tipo double, ¿es ese el problema por el que no se muestra correctamente la información?

Cuando muestro esa columna (pr_gastos_detalle) en otro JTable diferente sin hacer uso de UNION si muestra correctamente el ABONO, ¿Que puedo hacer para que se muestra correctamente la informacion? De antemano muchas gracias...

Comment: Estas usando algún patrón como DAO? Si es así muestra como obtienes los datos  y como los ingresas al JTable. La forma que se muestra en la imagen me hace acordar a cuando se usa toString() en un objeto sin sobrescribir el método.

Comment: Amigo, edite la pregunta para explicarme mejor, los datos los muestro con un Resultset, utilizo una librería llamada Dbutils que me facilita el proceso.